# Ending the process which is using the file on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, process

For my application to work, I need to delete a file which is a Calendar Cache file on Mac. If I do it manually it goes to trash with no problems, it is just not emptying the trash afterwards, but it is fine for me. I tried to run my Java application with a method to delete that same file but the method failed. I used file.delete() method. Are there any ways of deleting that file? Is there a way to stop the process that is using that file? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
File fin = new File("yourfile.txt");
for (File file : fin.listFiles()) {
    FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(file);
}
```

Comment: I get "package FileDeleteStrategy does not exist".

Comment: Apologies, you need the Apache Commons package also: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/